# Generate list of random number with condition - numpy

Tags: pandas, numpy, random, numpy-ndarray

I would like to generate a list of 15 integers with sum 12, minimum value is 0 and maximum is 6.

I tried following code

```
def generate(low,high,total,entity):
   while sum(entity)!=total:
       entity=np.random.randint(low, high, size=15)
   return entity
```

But above function is not working properly. It is too much time consuming.
Please let me know the efficient way to generate such numbers?

Comment: Well strictly speaking it is working, but generate and test is usually not very efficient. It here will usually take tenthousands of generates, before you generate a correct sequence.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem is there any other quick method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The above will, strictly speaking work. But for 15 numbers between 0 and 6, the odds of generating 12 is not that high. In fact we can calculate the number of possibilities with:

*F(s, 1) = 1* for *0≤s≤6*
and

*F(s, n) = Σ<sup>6</sup><sub>i=0</sub>F(s-i, n-1)*.

We can calculate that with a value:

```
from functools import lru_cache

@lru_cache()
def f(s, n, mn, mx):
    if n < 1:
        return 0
    if n == 1:
        return int(mn <= s <= mx)
    else:
        if s < mn:
            return 0
        return sum(f(s-i, n-1, mn, mx) for i in range(mn, mx+1))
```

That means that there are 9'483'280 possibilities, out of 4'747'561'509'943 total possibilities to generate a sum of 12, or 0.00019975%. It will thus take approximately 500'624 iterations to come up with such solution.

We thus should better aim to find a straight-forward way to generate such sequence. We can do that by each time calculating the probability of generating a number: the probability of generating *i* as number as first number in a sequence of *n* numbers that sums up to *s* is *F(s-i, n-1, 0, 6)/F(s, n, 0, 6)*. This will guarantee that we generate a *uniform* list over the list of possibilities, if we would each time draw a uniform number, then it will not match a uniform distribution over the entire list of values that match the given condition:

We can do that recursively with:

```
from numpy import choice

def sumseq(n, s, mn, mx):
    if n > 1:
        den = f(s, n, mn, mx)
        val, = choice(
            range(mn, mx+1),
            1,
            p=[f(s-i, n-1, mn, mx)/den for i in range(mn, mx+1)]
        )
        yield val
        yield from sumseq(n-1, s-val, mn, mx)
    elif n > 0:
        yield s
```

With the above function, we can generate numpy arrays:

```
>>> np.array(list(sumseq(15, 12, 0, 6)))
array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 3, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 1])
>>> np.array(list(sumseq(15, 12, 0, 6)))
array([0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 4, 1, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 2])
>>> np.array(list(sumseq(15, 12, 0, 6)))
array([0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 3, 1, 3, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1])
>>> np.array(list(sumseq(15, 12, 0, 6)))
array([5, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1])
>>> np.array(list(sumseq(15, 12, 0, 6)))
array([0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0])
```

Comment: Isn't it a multinomial distribution defined in some, frankly, strange way?

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux: that could be the case, I will try to take a look at that. I had as idea that (a) the implementation should be straight-forward, so without a "reject", and (2) that it as if you would have drawn from a uniform sampling, and then do rejection. If I take a look at the formulas, it might be the case, although proving it will probably take some work :)

Comment: If you find something interesting, I would appreciate if you send me a message, thank you

Comment: I updated my answer and believe we proposed different solutions, please take a look at it

Answer (score 2):

You could try it implementing it a little bit differently.

```py
import random
def generate(low,high,goal_sum,size=15):
    output = []
    for i in range(size):
        new_int = random.randint(low,high)
        if sum(output) + new_int <= goal_sum:
            output.append(new_int)
        else:
            output.append(0)
    random.shuffle(output)
    return output
```

Also, if you use np.random.randint, your high will actually be high-1

Answer (score 2):

Well, there is a simple and natural solution - use distribution which by definition provides you array of values with the fixed sum. Simplest one is [Multinomial Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_distribution). The only code to add is to check and reject (and repeat sampling) if some sampled value is above maximum.

Along the lines

```
import numpy as np

def sample_sum_interval(n, p, maxv):
    while True:
        q = np.random.multinomial(n, p)
        v = np.where(q > maxv)
        if len(v[0]) == 0: # if len(v) > 0, some values are outside the range, reject
            return q
    return None

np.random.seed(32345)

k    = 15
n    = 12
maxv = 6
p = np.full((k), np.float64(1.0)/np.float64(k), dtype=np.float64) # probabilities

q = sample_sum_interval(n, p, maxv)
print(q)
print(np.sum(q))

q = sample_sum_interval(n, p, maxv)
print(q)
print(np.sum(q))

q = sample_sum_interval(n, p, maxv)
print(q)
print(np.sum(q))
```

UPDATE

I quickly looked at @WillemVanOnsem proposed method, and I believe it is different from multinomial used by myself.

If we look at multinomial PMF, and assume equal probabilities for all `k` numbers,
p<sub>1</sub> = ... = p<sub>k</sub>  = 1/k, then we could write PMF as

PMF(x<sub>1</sub>,...x<sub>k</sub>)=n!/(x<sub>1</sub>!...x<sub>k</sub>!) p<sub>1</sub><sup>x<sub>1</sub></sup>...p<sub>k</sub><sup>x<sub>k</sub></sup> = 
n!/(x<sub>1</sub>!...x<sub>k</sub>!) k<sup>-x<sub>1</sub></sup>...k<sup>-x<sub>k</sub></sup> = n!/(x<sub>1</sub>!...x<sub>k</sub>!) k<sup>-Sum<sub>i</sub>x<sub>i</sub></sup> = n!/(x<sub>1</sub>!...x<sub>k</sub>!) k<sup>-n</sup>

Obviously, probabilities of particular x<sub>1</sub>...x<sub>k</sub> combinations would be different from each other due to factorials in denominator (modulo permutations, of course), which is different from @WillemVanOnsem approach where all of them would have equal probabilities to appear, I believe.

Moral of the story - those methods produce different distributions.